# Edge case of a recursion

Tags: if-statement, recursion

Here is the code which is correctly running

```
public double f(double x,long n,double ans){

    if(n <= 0){

        return ans;
    }
    if(n%2==0){
        ans=f(x*x,n/2,ans);
    }
    else{
        ans=f(x,n-1,ans*x);

    }
    return ans;
}

public double myPow(double x, long n) {
    double ans=f( x, Math.abs(n),1);
    return n>0 ? ans : 1/ans;

}
```

Below code is giving runtime error

```
 public double f(double x,long n,double ans){
    if(n == 0){

        return ans;
    }
    if(n%2==0){
        ans=f(x*x,n/2,ans);
    }
    else{
        ans=f(x,n-1,ans*x);

    }
    return ans;
}

public double myPow(double x, long n) {
    double ans=f( x, Math.abs(n),1);
    return n>0 ? ans : 1/ans;

}
```

This question is from the leetcode pow(x,n) . I tried to solve this using recursion . I wanted to return when the value of n becomes 0 which is running correct by adding condition if(n <=0 ) but if I change this condition to if(n==0) gives me runtime error of stack overflow . For me these two works same but behaving differently . I don't know why?

Comment: What values of `x` and `n` are you calling the function with?